# Why can't I focus on an anchor like this?

Tags: html, css, focus

I had some CSS like this:

```
a {
    display: block
}

a:focus {
    background: #000
}
```

And an anchor like this:

```
<a href="">Hi!</a>
```

why can't I focus on it by clicking? I know it redirects but one would assume for a split second the background would go black. Whats up?

Comment: because focus is NOT the same as active. focus is what happens when you tab your way through the website links. it focuses on what link you are on. active is what happens when the link is clicked. however, sometimes websites style them similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all browsers give elements focus when clicked. I believe Internet Explorer does, but Google Chrome certainly doesn't. If you're looking to apply a style when the mouse is down on the element, consider `:active` instead:

```
a:active {
    background: #000;
}
```

You can compare the two live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/gCftV/). On [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/gCftV/show), <kbd>Tab</kbd> once and the first one should get the focus and the border.

Comment: I understand this. I just found it odd that I couldnt focus from clicking an anchor

Answer (score 1):

a:active would give you the desired result (I use this for button press background images)